# 301 redirect url with all url's that start with main url - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We want to make a 301 redirect in the htacces in our wordpress installation for the following situation. This morning in our webmaster tools we see 8000 new 404 pages not found. In the image below we have made a printscreen. We do not know were these url's come from because we do not use this url structure. As you can see in the printscreen everything starts with:

order/order.html?AddID  for example: order/order.html?AddID=1014&Rand=920505296661072670

It looks like the old owner of the url has something to do with this. Now we want to redirect everything that starts with order/order.html?AddID to the homepage. At this moment we see 8000 not found with exactly the same url and only a different AddID.

Is this possible and if so does someone has the best way to redirect these url's?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just tell Google not to take into account these url parameters. In **Webmaster tools**, go to `Exploration -> URL Parameters` and declare that `AddID` and `Rand` do not change the page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code just below `RewriteBase` line in your WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^AddID=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^order/order\.html$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```